# Loading Images into a UITableView Asynchronously iOS 5

Tags: iphone, image, ios5, tableview, download

I'm struggling to get my tableView scrolling smoothly when loading images into the cell. At the moment I'm doing:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (self.newsFeedArray != nil) {

    NewsFeedCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NewsCell"];

    self.singleStory = [self.newsFeedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *imageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.singleStory valueForKey:@"image_primary"]];
    NSURL *imageLink = [NSURL URLWithString:imageURL];
    cell.newsFeedImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageLink]];
    cell.newsTitleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.singleStory valueForKey:@"title"]];

    return cell;

} else {

    NewsFeedCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"LoadingCell"];
    return cell;
}

}
```

I've tried loading the images in on a background thread, but it takes the object out of the array and means it only loads in the first image 10 times.

I've tried implementing LazyTableImages but got confused and lost with what I actually needed.
Advice/help/work arounds would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). This framework makes async request easy, using blocks. They even have a category for `UIImageView` that will retrieve an image from a server.

Comment: See the Apple's [LazyTableImages](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) and see this post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083454/objective-c-custom-lazy-load-images-uitableview-cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083454/objective-c-custom-lazy-load-images-uitableview-cell). It might help.