# objective-c image not appearing in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have NSMutableArray , which contains string, datetime, and `UIImage`. **everything is show in my UITableView without image**.

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *cellIdentifier =@"Cell";
        CustomCell *customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        contact = res[indexPath.row];

        NSString *titleNews = contact[@"title"];
        NSString *newsDateTime = contact[@"datetime"];
        NSString *NewsImageName = contact[@"featured_image"];

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:NewsImageName ];

        customCell.customFirstNameLabel.text = titleNews;
        customCell.customLastnameLabel.text = newsDateTime;
        customCell.customImageView.image =image;

        return customCell;
    }
```

i am trying show data from here .

```
{
        datetime = "2015-09-10 13:35:33";
        "featured_image" = "http://198.72.115.125/~pratidin/assets/news_images/2015/09/10/thumbnails/bdp-001.jpg";
        "item_id" = 102235;
        "main_news_url" = "http://198.72.115.125/~pratidin/api/detailnews/102235";
        "main_url" = "http://198.72.115.125/~pratidin/api/topnews";
        summery = "\U0997\U09a4 \U0995\U09af\U09bc\U09c7\U0995\U09ae\U09be\U09b8 \U09af\U09be\U09ac\U09a4 \U09ae\U09cb\U09ac\U09be\U0987\U09b2\U09aa\U09cd\U09b0\U09c7\U09ae\U09c0\U09b0\U09be \U0985\U09aa\U09c7\U0995\U09cd\U09b7\U09be\U09af\U09bc&#8230;";
        title = "\U098f\U09ac\U09be\U09b0 \U0986\U0987\U09ab\U09cb\U09a8 \U09ec\U098f\U09b8 \U0993 \U09ec\U098f\U09b8 \U09aa\U09cd\U09b2\U09be\U09b8";
    }
```

this my view .
[image]
would someone help me out how to solve this

Comment: @EICaptain check .. i gave more in details

Comment: its imageurl...you can not set image directly with imagename if its image url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its image url...you can't set image directly by image name...You have to get data from url like this...

```
NSURL *imgURL = [NSURL URLWithString:NewsImageName];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgURL];

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
   });
});
```

or directly set

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: NewsImageName]];
```

Comment: thanks a lost .. would u kindly help out one this .. How to load images using Lazy load in UITableView

Comment: glad it helps...and check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083454/objective-c-custom-lazy-load-images-uitableview-cell  or this ...https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: i just know one more think . i just want to load an other view using this information .. customCell.customFirstNameLabel.text = titleNews; customCell.customLastnameLabel.text = newsDateTime; customCell.customImageView.image =image; after i clicked - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{}  would you kindly let me know ?

Comment: check this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Answer (score 2):

Here your data source contact[@"featured_image"] is an url. So you must load image from url. You can use SDWebImage.framework to load image

```
            [cell.imageview sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:contact[@"featured_image"]] placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageCacheMemoryOnly completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
                if (image) {
                     [cell.imageview setImage:image];
                }
            }];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to load the image contents from the URL first:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier =@"Cell";
    CustomCell *customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    contact = res[indexPath.row];

    NSString *titleNews = contact[@"title"];
    NSString *newsDateTime = contact[@"datetime"];
    NSString *NewsImageName = contact[@"featured_image"];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:NewsImageName]]];
    //UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:NewsImageName ];

    customCell.customFirstNameLabel.text = titleNews;
    customCell.customLastnameLabel.text = newsDateTime;
    customCell.customImageView.image =image;

    return customCell;
}
```

Be aware that this will be a synchronous fetching of the images. I suggest you checking the LazyTableImages functions: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html
Or any image caching library like https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: i just know one more think . i just want to load an other view using this information .. customCell.customFirstNameLabel.text = titleNews;
    customCell.customLastnameLabel.text = newsDateTime;
    customCell.customImageView.image =image;  after user clicked - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{}

Answer (score 1):

Please NSLog your image, and the frame of imageView.

And the `[UIImage imageNamed:NewsImageName ];` only load from main bundle, it seems like you are loading image from internet.

Another possible is that you have set the wrong frame so it disappeared.

You are supposed to write in this way

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]];

UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: NewsImageName]];
```